# Passing member function pointer to member object in c++

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I have a problem with using a pointer to function in C++. Here is my example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class bar
{
public:
    void (*funcP)();
};

class foo
{
public:
    bar myBar;
    void hello(){cout << "hello" << endl;};
};

void byebye()
{
    cout << "bye" << endl;
}


int main()
{
    foo testFoo;

    testFoo.myBar.funcP = &byebye;         //OK
    testFoo.myBar.funcP = &testFoo.hello;  //ERROR
    return 0;
}
```

Compilator returns an error at `testFoo.myBar.funcP = &testFoo.hello;`:

> **ISO C++ forbids taking the address of a bound member function to form a
>   pointer to member function.  Say
>   '&foo::hello'**
>
> **cannot convert 'void (foo::*)()' to 'void (*)()' in assignment**

So i tried it like this:

```
class bar
{
public:
    void (*foo::funcP)();
};
```

But now the compilator adds one more:

> **'foo' has not been declared**

Is there a way make it work?

Thanks in advance for suggestions

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Taking everyone's suggestions together, your final solution will look like:

```
#include <iostream> 
using std::cout;
usind std::endl;

class foo; // tell the compiler there's a foo out there.

class bar 
{ 
public: 
    // If you want to store a pointer to each type of function you'll
    // need two different pointers here:
    void (*freeFunctionPointer)();
    void (foo::*memberFunctionPointer)();
}; 

class foo 
{ 
public: 
    bar myBar; 
    void hello(){ cout << "hello" << endl; }
}; 

void byebye() 
{ 
    cout << "bye" << endl; 
} 


int main() 
{ 
    foo testFoo; 

    testFoo.myBar.freeFunctionPointer = &byebye;
    testFoo.myBar.memberFunctionPointer = &foo::hello;

    ((testFoo).*(testFoo.myBar.memberFunctionPointer))(); // calls foo::hello()
    testFoo.myBar.freeFunctionPointer();   // calls byebye()
    return 0; 
}
```

The [C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.5) has some guidance on how to simplify the syntax.

Taking Chris' idea and running with it, you could get yourself something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl;

class foo;
typedef void (*FreeFn)();
typedef void (foo::*MemberFn)();

class bar
{
public:
  bar() : freeFn(NULL), memberFn(NULL) {}
  void operator()(foo* other)
  {
    if (freeFn != NULL) { freeFn(); }
    else if (memberFn != NULL) { ((other)->*(memberFn))(); }
    else { cout << "No function attached!" << endl; }
  }

  void setFreeFn(FreeFn value) { freeFn = value; memberFn = NULL; }
  void setMemberFn(MemberFn value) { memberFn = value; freeFn = NULL; }
private:
  FreeFn freeFn;
  MemberFn memberFn;
};

class foo
{
public:
  bar myBar;
  void hello() { cout << "foo::hello()" << endl; }
  void operator()() { myBar(this); }
};

void bye() { cout << "bye()" << endl; }

int main()
{
  foo testFoo;

  testFoo();

  testFoo.myBar.setMemberFn(&foo::hello);
  testFoo();

  testFoo.myBar.setFreeFn(&bye);
  testFoo();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice, but how to run the function that memberFunctionPointer points at?
  
testFoo.myBar.*memberFuncionPointer() results error

Comment: @moomin: I added a correct sample of calling the functions this time.

Comment: Just for completeness, you might want to add a default constructor to `bar` to set both pointers to `0`. You could set up the class so that it always only has one member set (i.e. setting one member `0`s the other) and then add an `operator()` function that calls the set member. Though it'll be more complicated than that in the end.

Answer (score 12):

As the error says, methods belong to the class, not to individual instances. For this reason pointers to free functions and pointers to non-static methods are completely different things. You'll also need an instance to call the method on.

```
//declaring and taking the address of a foo's method 
void (foo::*method)() = &foo::hello; //as the compiler nicely suggests

//calling a function through pointer
free_func();

//calling a method through pointer
foo instance;
(instance.*method)();
```

You can use libraries like [Boost.Bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bind/bind.html) and [Boost.Function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/function.html) (also in std::tr1 I think) to abstract away the difference and also bind an instance to the method:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

using namespace std;

class foo
{
public:
    void hello(){cout << "hello" << endl;};
};

void byebye()
{
    cout << "bye" << endl;
}


int main()
{
    foo testFoo;

    boost::function<void()> helloFunc(boost::bind(&foo::hello, testFoo));
    boost::function<void()> byeFunc(byebye);

    helloFunc();
    byeFunc();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could please explain how to run the 
"hello()" from testFoo.myBar?
I did 'testFoo.myBar.funcP = &foo::hello;' 
but '(testFoo.myBar.*funcP)();' 
returns 'funcP was not declared...' during compilation

Answer (score 1):

To make your second option work, declare foo so the compiler knows that it is a class.

Also note that your function pointer syntax is incorrect.  The `*` comes just before the name of the variable:

```
class foo;

class bar
{
public:
    void (foo::*funcP)();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

forward foo's declaration in front of bar:

```
class foo;
```