# Class function pointer as parameter

Tags: c++, function, pointers, parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to best pass methods into methods of the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260260/how-to-best-pass-methods-into-methods-of-the-same-class)

I've never had problems passing a function pointer as parameter. This works:

```
void functionThatTakesFPTR(void(*function)(int), int someValue){ 
    function(someValue);
   }

void printValue(int value){
    std::printf("%d",value);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    functionThatTakesFPTR(&printValue, 8);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

However, passing object function doesn't

```
void MyClass::setter(float value){ }

void MyClass::testFunction(void(*setterPtr)(float)){ }

void MyClass::someFunc(){
     testFunction(&(this->setter));
}
```

To me this looks like passing the address of this instead of the function, and I'm a bit confused. Is it possible to do so? And is it possible to pass the function pointer of object of another class (of instance MyClass2) ?

Edit: Error I'm getting is "class 'MyClass' has no member 'setter' ".

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/pointers-to-members.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that a call to a method also requires a reference to the class instance. You can't simply call a class method like a stand-alone function.

You need to read about [Pointer-to-Member Functions](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/article.php/c17401/C-Tutorial-PointertoMember-Function.htm).